# Красный шрифт в названии файла

Tags: android, android-studio, контроль-версий

Утром этого дня меня удивило: Открыв проект в студии все имена файлов отображаются красным шрифтом, как это фиксить?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Они у вас в индекс Git- а не добавлены

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Просто добавьте и индекс контроля версий, не важно - git, mercurial или еще что у вас там. тогда они станут зелеными, если файлов с такими именами нет в репозитории, если же есть и вы что-то изменили - станут голубыми, если незакомиченных изменений нет - будут белыми

Comment: Я только недавно начал осваивать git как мне это сделать?

Comment: @Felay в консоли git add . для добавления всех файлов, либо git add имя_файла для добавления конкретного. Либо во вкладке VCS->Git->Add to VCS добавит в индекс выбранные файлы

Comment: @Felay а вообще часто IDE при создании нового файла предлагает сразу добавить в индекс

Comment: В консоль ввел: git add .    В ответ получил угрожающее сообщение: 
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in .idea/gradle.xml.    Что оно значит?

Comment: @Felay у вас в этом файле стоит символ переноса строки из Unix/Linux (LF), судя по всему вы работаете в винде, поэтому символы переноса строки будут изменены на виндовые с возвратом каретки(CRLF). Если хотите отключить это предупреждение, выполните настройку гита git config core.autocrlf true

Answer (score 0):

Снизу в **Android Studio** есть вкладка терминал “Terminal”.

Введите следующие команду:

```
git add . 
git commit -m "Добавление моих файлов в индекс. Создание коммита для них."
git push origin [branch_name(имя ветки в которой вы работаете)]
```

Примечание: имя ветки находится в нижнем правом углу.

Пример: **Git: hotfix**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]